# Flink large size / small advance sliding window performance

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

**My use case**

- the input is raw events keyed by an ID
- I'd like to count the total number of events over the past 7 days for each ID.
- the output would be every 10 mins advance
- Logically, this will be handled by a sliding window of size 7 day and advance 10min

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458497/apache-flink-how-to-apply-multiple-counting-window-functions) laid out a good optimization solution by a tumbling window of 1 day

So my logic would be like

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

val oneDayCounts = joins
  .keyBy(keyFunction)
  .map(t => (t.key, 1L, t.timestampMs))
  .keyBy(0)
  .timeWindow(Time.days(1))

val sevenDayCounts = oneDayCounts
  .keyBy(0)
  .timeWindow(Time.days(7), Time.minutes(10))
  .sum(1)

// single reducer
sevenDayCounts
  .windowAll(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(10)))
```

P.S. forget about the performance concern of the single reducer.

**Question**

If I understand correctly, however, this would mean a single event would produce 7*24*6=1008 records due to the nature of the sliding window. So my question is how can I reduce the sheer amount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a JIRA ticket -- [FLINK-11276](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11276) -- and a [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ziVsuW_HQnvJr_4a9yKwx_LEnhVkdlde2Z5l6sx5HlY/edit#heading=h.qr0nyau4crad) on the topic of doing this more efficiently.

I also recommend you take a look at this [paper](http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/powibol/assets/publications/traub-scotty-icde-2018.pdf) and [talk](https://www.ververica.com/flink-forward-berlin/resources/efficient-window-aggregation-with-stream-slicing) about *Efficient Window Aggregation with Stream Slicing*.